# How do I parse a split String from a text document

Tags: java

How to get the first line after split string.
So i have a text document, and the inside of the text document is...
(test:result)
I want to just print out the "result".

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   System.out.println("Reading File from Java code");
   //Name of the file
   String fileName="C:\\Users\\Olive\\Desktop\\accounts.txt";
   try{

      //Create object of FileReader
      FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

      //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
      BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

      //Variable to hold the one line data
      String line =" ";
      String result = line.trim();

      // Read file line by line and print on the console
      while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {
        System.out.println(result.trim());

      }
      //Close the buffer reader
      bufferReader.close();
   }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());                      
   }
```

Comment: Please provide an example input file and desired output and show what you've tried and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: `System.out.println("test:result".split(":")[1]);`

Comment: Why do you do `String line =" ";` and `String result = line.trim();`? Utterly unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String mystr = "test:result".split(":")[1];
```

OR use substring like:

```
String str = "test:result";
String mystr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
```